# Count of combo box is 1 but the combo box is empty

Tags: ms-access, combobox, count, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to understand why the count of one of my combo boxes keeps returning 1 when it's empty. The code in the Control Source for the textbox that is counting the values in the combo box is simply:

```
=[Combo781].[ListCount]
```

Why might this be? I can provide more info if asked, it's just that I'm not sure what else to check...

Comment: ListCount counts the rows in the combobox list. Are you saying there are no rows in the list?

Comment: @June7 Yes (or at least, it appears blank). When I hit the drop down it is blank.

Comment: Just did a test, created combobox without a RowSource. ListCount returns 1. Combobox with a RowSource shows correct count for the number of rows. So for the combobox dropdown to show even when there is no data, must be a single 'empty string' row.